# Using Bayes Factor to test Geometric vs Poisson distribution

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, model-selection, bayes-factors

I have a sample of 200 observations and need to test $H_0: X \sim Geom(p)$ vs. $H_1: X \sim Pois(\lambda)$. Prior distributions are $U[0, 1]$ and $U[0, 20]$. I need to construct a bayes test to distinguish $H_0 $ from $H_1$ with different significance levels (0.05, 0.1, 0.01) using modeling.

My approach is to calculate [bayes factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor) $K$. The next thing I wanted to do was to sample many points from Geometric and Poisson distributions $K$ and find their percentiles. Then if $K$ for my sample is inside these percentiles for one of the distributions, job is done.

However, I faced two problems.

1. I used Python to calculate integrals for K. If sample is larger than 20 points, everything goes bad and I get nan. If I get random subsets of these 200 samples, I get different results.
2. Most of these results are outside of found percentile intervals.

How to interpret that and how to cope with problem 1? Integrals look like not easy to compute by hand.